# Pass an empty value to an OData V2 Edm.Time property

Tags: odata, abap, sap-gateway

I have a variable type *time* but sometimes this variable doesn't have anything.

When it is initial, it shouldn't be `"000000"`, I want an empty value without anything (no zeros). Let me explain my problem with the code:

```
IF lwa_hora IS INITIAL.
   CLEAR lwa_hora.
   ls_entity-hora = lwa_hora. " Result: 000000 but I don't want any zero
ELSE.
   ls_entity-hora = lwa_hora. " Result: 000000
ENDIF.
```

I tried with `CLEAR` but nothing happens.

I need this is because in the JavaScript frontend client logic, I need the OData property to contain a falsy value (E.g. `null` or an empty string `""`).

But it always has the value `"000000"` which is **not** an empty string. Is it possible to make something in the backend to "clear" the variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The time data-type in abap (`t`) is a value-type. It's internally implemented as an integer counting the seconds since midnight. 0 seconds since midnight is a valid value, so it can't have a null-value.

However, ABAP allows you to create a reference to any value-type:

```
hora TYPE REF TO t.
```

That means `hora` will be a reference to a variable of `TYPE t`. Initially, this reference will be unbound, which is conceptually very similar to a null-reference in other programming languages. You can check that with:

```
IF ls_entity-hora IS BOUND.
...
IF ls_entity-hora IS NOT BOUND.
```

You can assign a time value with `GET REFERENCE OF lwa_hora INTO ls_entity-hora`. But now you have a reference to an existing variable. Change the value of `lwa_hora`, and the value of `ls_entity-hora` also changes. That might not always be what you want. So it might be better to create a new piece of data in memory for our reference to point to:

```
CREATE DATA ls_entity-hora.
```

Now `ls_entity-hora` is no longer unbound (or "null" if you want to call it that), it points to a new time-value of `000000`. If you want to read or change the value of this nameless piece of data this reference points to, then you can do this with the dereferencing-operator `->*`:

```
ls_entity-hora->* = lwa_hora.
```

If you intentionally want to set a reference to unbound (or "set the reference to null"), you can do that by clearing the reference:

```
CLEAR ls_entity-hora.
```

---

By the way: Representing a point in time by two separate variables of the types `d` and `t` fell out of fashion in the past decade. The current best practice for this situation is to use a single variable of type `TIMESTAMP` (if you need second precision) or `TIMESTAMPL` (if you need microsecond precision). A timestamp of `00000000000000` is obviously an illegal value, so it can be used to represent the absence of a point in time. This type also usually makes it much easier to communicate with a SAPUI5 frontend (like in your case), because many of the technologies for making oData services offer automatic conversion between Javascript `Date` and ABAP `TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to heap allocating the time would be to store  a boolean next to it, indicating whether it is set or not:

```
TYPES:
     BEGIN OF optional_time,
        time    TYPE t,
        is_null TYPE abap_bool,
     END OF optional_time.

DATA(no_time) = VALUE optional_time( is_null = abap_true ).

" Setting to null:
DATA(some_time) = no_time.
" Setting to some time:
some_time = VALUE #( time = '12:30' ).

IF some_time = no_time.
   " ...
ENDIF.
```

Answer (score 1):

This sort of things is probably better to handle on front-end than on back-end.

SAP Gateway serializes ABAP Date/time initial values to NULL in the OData response if the corresponding property is nullable. You need to make sure this property is set to `TRUE` like in this sample

[image]

you can also set this property in runtime

```
TRY .
 lo_action = model->get_entity_type( iv_entity_name = 'Z_REPORTType').                                                             
 lo_property = lo_action->get_property( iv_property_name = 'Requested_Date').
 lo_property->set_nullable( iv_nullable = abap_true ).
CATCH /iwbep/cx_mgw_busi_exception /iwbep/cx_mgw_med_exception /iwbep/cx_mgw_tech_exception INTO DATA(lo_exception).
ENDTRY.
```